# How to calculate a time between two times with one day off?

Tags: java, android

I have a Do Not Disturb system that mutes the sounds of my android app if the current time is in Do not disturb range time.
It works fine if I use a range time just between a day, but I dont know how to write it with one day off, For example at 11:00 pm to 1:00 am of the next day.

This is method that I used for detecting DND time:

```
private boolean isInDNDTime() {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    MyDate myDate = new MyDate(new Date());

    if (isDNDTwoDays()) {
        startTime.setTime(myDate.getYesterday().toDate());
        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDStartHourTime());
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDStartMinuteTime());

        endTime.setTime(myDate.getTomorrow().toDate());
        endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDEndHourTime());
        endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDEndMinuteTime());

    } else {
        startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDStartHourTime());
        startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDStartMinuteTime());

        endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDEndHourTime());
        endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDEndMinuteTime());
    }

    return now.after(startTime) && now.before(endTime);
}
```

Comment: Just distinguish between the two cases. Same day is "after start AND before end", different day is "after start OR before end"

Comment: How have you tried it so far? What didn't work? Which is the smallest API level your app is supporting?

Comment: @deHaar I edited the question, And the smallest API level for my app is Lollipop (21).

Answer (score 0):

Pls try below code

```
 private boolean isInDNDTime() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        MyDate myDate = new MyDate(new Date());

        if (isDNDTwoDays()) {
            startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            endTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

           // startTime.setTime(myDate.getYesterday().toDate());
            startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDStartHourTime());
            startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDStartMinuteTime());

           // endTime.setTime(myDate.getTomorrow().toDate());
            endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDEndHourTime());
            endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDEndMinuteTime());

        } else {
            startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDStartHourTime());
            startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDStartMinuteTime());

            endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, getDNDEndHourTime());
            endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getDNDEndMinuteTime());
        }

        return now.after(startTime) && now.before(endTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a modern API for tasks like this, it is called `java.time` and is available from Java 8. The following example illustrates how to do that with a few lines of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create sample data
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 2, 19, 12, 30);
    LocalDateTime timeInDND = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 2, 21, 12, 30);

    // just check if the time is equal to start or end or is between them
    if (timeInDND.equals(start) || timeInDND.equals(end)
            || (timeInDND.isAfter(start) && timeInDND.isBefore(end))) {
        System.out.println(timeInDND.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) 
                + " is in the DND period");
    } else {
        System.err.println(timeInDND.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) 
                + " is not in the DND period");
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately**, your support of Android API levels below 26 requires an external library, the [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) because `java.time` is available from API level 26. You can check another question about [how to use the ThreeTenABP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).